# My app accesses data on encrypted sdcard without en-/decrypting

Tags: android, encryption, android-sdcard, sd-card

One of our users reported a problem with accessing data on an encrypted sdcard on Android using our App for Android.

He is using Android 6.0.1 on a Galaxy Note 4 (SM-N910F). The app uses the Storage Access Framework in combination with a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to access the sdcard data. The sdcard is configured to be encrypted.

As long as only the app itself is involved everything works fine. Data on the sdcard can be read and written without problems. All such data is stored on the sdcard and can be retrieved. As soon as data which has been written by another app is read by our app, our app only reads encrypted data. In addition when ejecting the sdcard and inspecting the data written by our app using a computer the data is not encrypted at all. Our app just writes the cleartext data directly to the sdcard. Data written by other apps is encrypted. Another interesting thing is, that after reinserting the sdcard the device seems to encrypt the non encrypted files written by our app. Afterwards our app will start to only read encrypted data from the sdcard.

When disabling sdcard encryption everything works just fine.

So it seems like our app uses the sdcard but somehow bypasses the configured sdcard encryption. I am not sure how that is even possible. I could not find any bug reports regarding this problem. Is this the expected behaviour when using the Storage Access Framework? Does anybody have any hints or tips on how to mitigate the described problems? Other apps seem to handle sdcard access just fine.

To illustrate the problem:

```
    Apps          |                Android System
                  | 
#------------#    |                                   #--------#
| Our App    | <---------------- IO^1 --------------> |        |
#------------#    |                                   |        |
                  |                                   | SDCard |
#------------#    |   #----------------------#        |        |
| Other Apps | <-IO-> | En-/Decryption Layer | <-IO-> |        |
#------------#    |   #----------------------#        #--------#
```

`^1` This should not bypass the en-/decryption layer but obviously does.

Comment: `As soon as data which has been written by another app is read..` Read by which app? `.. our app can only access encrypted data.`. But there is only encrypted data on the card (well that is what i presume) so what do you want to access uncrypted?

Comment: I mean "which has been written by another apps is read by our app". I want to access the cleartext data when reading/writing to the sdcard. en- and decryption shall be done by the system.

Modified the question and added an illustration of the problem. In my understanding enabling sdcard encryption should add an en-/decryption layer to all sdcard access which is transparent to the apps. Alls apps should still read/write cleartext data and must not care about encryption. The system will handle it. Our app does seem to directly access the sdcard without en-/decryption applied.

Comment: What im missing in the whole story is how everything normally works. On your own phone, are the files encrypted if you inspect the card on a computer?

Comment: When sdcard encryption is enabled all the files on the sdcard written by other apps are encrypted when inspecting them on the computer. This does NOT apply to files written by our app. Those files are not encrypted at all until the sdcard is reinserted into the phone which causes all cleartext files currently there to be encrypted as well.

Comment: I now even understand less. You start your post with one user having a problem with one specific device. I assumed that on other devices it would work as you expect: encryption transparant. Thats why i named your phone. What i have to conclude now is that it never worked. On not one phone. Can you clear this up?

Comment: OK didn't pay attention the ```on your onw phone``` part in your comment. I do not have the possibility to test this myself because I do not have a samsung device available. On the phones I have there is no sdcard encryption available. I assume it never works on Samsung phones with sdcard encryption enabled but am not sure about this because I can not test it. I instructed some other people to test this szenario, didn't get feedback yet.